# Why does .Net XMLSerializer adds xsi and xsd namespaces?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces

Why does .Net XMLSerializer add xsd and xsi namespaces by default ?

Comment: I went through many online posts and learned that many developers don't require

Comment: I know it doesn't hurt to have these default namespaces in our output xml, as long as we don't use xsi and xsd namespace prefixes. Also, I know how to remove them. But, it makes me curious to know why does Microsoft adds these by default in the first place ?